# Masking a multidimensional NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to mask a multidimensional array, say the 4D array `A` of shape `N` x `N` x `N` x `N`, where I have a different mask (`a`, `b`, and `c`) for the last three dimension. So `a`, `b`, and `c` are vectors with values `True` and `False` of length `N`. Trying to mask `A` as `A[:,a,b,c]` yields an exception (what does this try to do?), `A[:,:,:,d][:,:,c][:,b]` works,
but creates unnecessary intermediates. If I had masks for every dimension, I would use them as `A[numpy.ix_(a, b, c, d)]` to create an intermediate indexing array, but I do not want to create a dummy mask `a` that is `True` everywhere. Thanks.

Edit:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(3**4).reshape((3,3,3,3))
a = np.asarray([True, True, True])
b = np.asarray([False, False, True])
c = np.asarray([True, True, False])

B = A[:,:,:,c][:,:,b][:,a]
print(B)

B2 = A[:,a,b,c]
print(B2)
```

output:

```
[[[[ 6  7]]

  [[15 16]]

  [[24 25]]]


 [[[33 34]]

  [[42 43]]

  [[51 52]]]


 [[[60 61]]

  [[69 70]]

  [[78 79]]]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    B2 = A[:,a,b,c]
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast 
together with shapes (3,) (1,) (2,)
```

Comment: Doesn't `A[numpy.ix_(a, b, c, d)]` work?

Comment: Ooops! You are right `numpy.ix_` does work in this case! I tried to make the question more general but changed the problem at hand too much.
In my case I actually only want to mask the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th dimension. So something like `A[:,numpy.ix_(b,c,d)]` instead of `A[:,:,:,d][:,:,c][:,b]`. The former however, results in `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(A[:,np.ix_(b,c,d)])
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (1)`

Comment: Please edit the question likewise.

Comment: For that specific case : `np.moveaxis(np.moveaxis(A,0,-1)[np.ix_(b,c,d)],-1,0)`. For the generic case, you might want to work with `slice`.

Comment: I edited the question and thanks for your help. Could you give me an example of how I would use `slice` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using a transpose trick:

```
In [19]: (A.T[np.ix_(c.T, b.T, a.T)]).T
Out[19]:
array([[[[ 6,  7]],

    [[15, 16]],

    [[24, 25]]],


   [[[33, 34]],

    [[42, 43]],

    [[51, 52]]],


   [[[60, 61]],

    [[69, 70]],

    [[78, 79]]]])
```